# How we can apply for crowdloan to participate in the auction?

Tags: crowdloan

What the steps for any chain to participate in the auction to get the slot.
Do we have any guide related to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start learning about this either through the [Substrate developer hub](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/how-to-guides/parachains/auctions-and-crowdloans/), or the [Polkadot wiki](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-auction).

Assuming that you are more interested in first trying this on a testnet, there is a dedicated document about [Rococo](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/connect-relay-and-parachains/acquire-a-testnet-slot/) as well.